# Change an IISExpress site's physicalPath on the command line

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, iis-express

What's the easiest way to accomplish this? I see there's lots of examples for appcmd relating to IIS proper, and using powershell for same, but I can't see an API of sorts for reconfiguring the `physicalPath` of a `<virtualDirectory/>` node for a given `/site`.

I guess I could load up the `applicationHost.config` with the App configuration classes, but seems pretty verbose.

I'm looking for a one-liner here really.

I tried asking on ServerFault but I think this is more of a dev question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a fit for your problem, but I found your question why trying to figure out how to alter visual studio's (IISExpress) webroot for a one off project.

I inherited a project with src and build tree in it. Skipping a long story I wanted to be able to bring this into our shops VS workflow and wanted to leverage VS/IISExpress out of sheer convenience.
The problem was getting visual studio/IISExpress to serve the deploy folder as the webroot.
I didn't want to alter a system wide setting and I really wanted something simple that could be checked into source control that another developer on the team could pull and just have the site work.

Ended up going with a rewrite rule

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="LocalDeployAlias" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/deploy/{R:0}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

This got the job done for me. Hope it helps.